# Cannot use "IgnoreCase" in Spring boot data JPA with SQL server database

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to communicate with an SQL Server database locally via Spring boot and Spring boot data JPA and I get the following error:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: Parameter 1 of function upper() has type STRING, but argument is of type java.lang.String

My method is defined as following:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    Optional<User> findByEmailIgnoreCase(String email);
}
```

It seems like SQL server does not support "IgnoreCase" once removed the code works. Is there a reason why I get this error the type is String.